# Which Canadian visa is required for Student Volunteer at Academic Conference?

Tags: visas, canada, working-visas

I hold an Indian passport and currently studying in the US on F-1 visa. I'll be attending an academic conference in Canada and I have been accepted as a student volunteer. The conference is for 5 days and I have an obligation to volunteer for 20 hours at this conference. I won't be paid for my volunteer work but my registration fee will be waived. Do I need a visitor visa or a work permit in this case? The online tool on Canada's immigration website is confusing me.

Comment: What did the conference organizers recommend?

Comment: They told me to refer the online tool on Canada's Immigration website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming you mean "[find out if you need a visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas-tool.asp)" I didn't find it confusing. You are a citizen of India without a US green card, so you need a visa. Your purpose in coming to Canada is to attend a conference or trade show. The website says you need an ETA for a business visit and can apply online. It didn't ask me if you were going to do any volunteer work.

If the **purpose** of coming to Canada was to do volunteer work (eg on a farm for the summer) then perhaps the tool would have led somewhere different. But your purpose in coming is to **attend the conference**. You still need to meet the [other eligibility requirements](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eligibility.html), but since you are a student in the US you need to leave Canada to complete your studies, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Still feel worried? Try the [definition of work](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/temporary-residents/foreign-workers/what-is-work.html) on the government website, which includes:

> ... other types of unpaid short-term work where the work is really incidental to the main reason that a person is visiting Canada and is not a competitive activity, even though non-monetary valuable consideration is received. For instance, if a tourist wishes to stay on a family farm and work part time just for room and board for a short period (i.e., one to four weeks), this person would not be considered a worker. Work on a farm that is expected to extend beyond four weeks would require a work permit.

By that logic, less than a week at a conference where all you get is conference admission would not be work.

*Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer or an immigration consultant. I am pasting stuff into a box from a government website. Make your own decisions.*